# AngularJS: Poll $resource on hashchange

Tags: angularjs

Ok, so I have an Angular module working as intended on pageload - with a url like site.com#/catalog/1234. The $resources fetches the data for the view on reload, but not on hashchange.

What do I need to add to get the hashchange to trigger a new fetch?

```
angular.module('Catalog', ['ngResource'])
.config( function( $routeProvider, $locationProvider ) {
    $routeProvider
        .when( '/catalog/:categoryid', {
            controller: 'CatalogListCtrl',
            templateUrl:'/layout/responsive/html/catalogListView.html'
        })
        .otherwise( { redirectTo:'/' } );
})
.factory( 'CatalogList', function( $resource, $routeParams ) {
    var list = $resource('/test/products.json?query=:categoryid', { categoryid : $routeParams.categoryid },  {
            query: { method: 'GET', isArray : true }
    });
    return list;
})
.controller( 'CatalogListCtrl', function ( $scope, CatalogList ) {
    $scope.products = CatalogList.query();
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by hashchange?

Comment: You can't really inject $routeParams into a service declaration, I don't think. Only controllers.

Comment: @blesh is correct. You can however inject $route and access the current parameter through $route.current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that the standard binding you set for the service confuses angular?

I would change your code the follow way, maybe you can try it.

```
angular.module('Catalog', ['ngResource'])
.config( function( $routeProvider, $locationProvider ) {
    $routeProvider
        .when( '/catalog/:categoryid', {
            controller: 'CatalogListCtrl',
            templateUrl:'/layout/responsive/html/catalogListView.html'
        })
        .otherwise( { redirectTo:'/' } );
})
.factory( 'CatalogList', function( $resource ) {
    return list = $resource('/test/products.json?query=:categoryid', {},  {});
})
.controller( 'CatalogListCtrl', function ( $scope, $routeParams, CatalogList ) {
    $scope.products = CatalogList.query({categoryid: $routeParams.categoryid});
});
```

I also removed some code which just repeats default values. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I think this is probably right... $routeParams is really meant to be consumed by a controller, not a service. however, you left a $routeParams in the service declaration that can go away.

Comment: Thank, works like a charm. $routeParams are for controllers - gotta remember that.

Thanks again!

Comment: @blesh oh yes you are right :) the $routeParams is not needed! Thanks.